# Is there a way for a limited user to just view the page of a post without being able to edit it?

Tags: user-roles

I have multiple types of users using WordPress. One type is contributor. Right now they can't publish a post, it as to be the Admin or Editor.

The problem I have is after the article is publish the contributors cannot re-access the page of the Post inside there WordPress account. It just says they don't have the rights.

So is there a way that they can view the Post page without being allowed to edit anything or if they do and save it, it will not save it?

Comment: But can you explain the purpose of allowing the contributor to see the `post-edit` page but not allowing to actually edit it. as the contributor can always see the list of posts and can see the content of the post in the front end

Answer (score 0):

Check out the User Role Editor plugin in the WP repository:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

You can edit the permissions of a role with this plugin.